Ordenar una lista por meses del año
soy novato en C#, pero me gustaría saber si hay la forma de ordenar una lista por los meses de año, Ejemplo: una vez q se remueva un items de dicha lista y se vuelva agregar el mismo items, la lista se ordene de acuerdo a los meses de año... gracias

Una lista de que??? de string? de datetime? de int?.... Favor agregar un ejemplo de la lista

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si hay muchas formas y depende de tu lista.. inclusive tenes algo que se llama sorted list y que ya se ordena sola...

Está bien que te hayas dado el tiempo de marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pero es aún más importante el haber respondido lo que te estoy consultando. Tu pregunta es irrespondible tal como está

Solución:
Usa IndexOf para ordenar según el orden de los meses.
var meses = new List<string> { "Enero", "Febrero", ..., "Diciembre" };
lista = lista.OrderBy(m => meses.IndexOf(m)).ToList();


La lista ya está ordenada ... ¿cual es la idea?

@Candid Moe
Entendí la pregunta de inmediato. El ejemplo claramente usa cadenas con los nombres de los meses. La idea es que, al modificar la lista, los meses mantengan su orden cronológico. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames es válida para manejar el idioma, pero añade una dependencia innecesaria para solo ordenar meses, cuyo orden es universal. Mi solución es más simple y flexible. No entiendo por qué se cerró la pregunta así.

No diste informacion de que typo tu lista es, asi que supongo que te voy a mostrar la solucion con List<DateTime> y List<string>.
Con List<DateTime> (Esto lo harias despues de que vos removiste un item):
miLista = miLista.OrderBy(x => x.Month).ToList();

Otra posibilidad con List<string> seria:
List<string> miLista = new List<string> { "Enero", "Diciembre", "Octubre", "Febrero", "Mayo", "Marzo", "Noviembre", "Septiembre", "Julio", "Junio", "Abril" };
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");

//Aca podes remover, añadir, etc...

miLista = miLista.OrderBy(x => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.ToList().IndexOf(x.ToLower())).ToList();

Perdoname si mi español no es perfecto.

Thank you brother, you are a sensei, excuse my English, greetings from Venezuela

@LisandroPedriquez jajaja denada, saludos de Suiza!

Osea... para ordenar la lista accedes a una lista ya ordenada de dichos meses??? Y no habría sido mejor directamente List<string> miLista = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.ToList();?? Porque eso es exactamente lo que es esa lista según la documentación...

@Benito-B A ver. No se si entendiste lo que pregunto el OP, pero te lo voy a explicar: El ya tiene una lista que no esta ordenada, y le remueve und item o le añade otro, etc... Despues de haber hecho eso el la quiere ordenar por los meses del año. Quizas no tiene 12 meses en su lista, quizas tenga solo 4 meses en su lista, igualmente la tenemos que ordenar por eso me fijo yo atraves de CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames para ordenar sus 4 meses en la lista por mes de año. Me entiendes? Perdoname si mi español no es perfecto.

Tu español es perfecto, deja de disculparte por él :) Efectivamente, si su lista no está completa esto tiene sentido... pero dado que la pregunta no tiene información alguna al respecto, es difícil de saber. Es el problema de responder preguntas mal formuladas, no sabes si estás respondiendo al problema que realmente tiene, o a uno que se ha causado él por no saber otra cosa.

@Benito-B Y si, tienes razon. Porque la pregunta esta mal formulada las respuestas son solo como especulaciones.
